# Angularjs Directive not populating page with partial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What am I doing wrong? The list partial is not populating into the view, but the Add page is. Each are connected via directives.

The console is throwing no errors, I don't believe the issue is within the controller because my app worked before i tried using directives.

Routes:

```
//ROUTING ---------------------------------------
UsersApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

  .state('List', {
    url: "/List",
    template: "<list-Users user='user' users-List='usersList'></list-Users>",

  })

  .state('AddUser', {
    url: "/Add",
    template: "<add-User new-User='newUser' users-List='usersList' add-New='addNew(newUser)'></add-User>",
  })

});
```

Directives:

```
UsersApp.directive('listUsers', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: '../../partials/userslist.html',
  scope: {
  usersList: '=',
  user: '=',
  } 
 };
});

UsersApp.directive('addUser', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  templateUrl: '../../partials/adduser.html',
  scope: {
   newUser: '=',
   addNew: '&'
  }
 };
});
```

List Page:

```
<div>
  <h2 style="display:table; width:35%; position:relative; font-family:sans-serif;">Users:</h2>
  <div class="userInfo">
    <br/>

    <div id="listInfo">

        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
            <li ng-repeat="user in usersList">

                <p class="userData"><a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="profilePopulate(user)" ng-model="user.firstName" ui-sref="UserProfile({id: user._id})">{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</a></p>
                <br/>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: you have multiple properties bound to the same variable name.  You are passing in a `user` object, and then trying to iterate `user in usersList`, which isn't going to work.

Comment: also, where are you actually setting `usersList` to anything other than a string with `'usersList'` as the content?

Comment: I think it might be your directive naming. The camel case gets in js needs to be snake case on the html. ```listUsers -> list-users```

Comment: @Claies I fixed the 'user' variable ambiguity, still no luck. Also, usersList is being populated via REST get service within my controller. I have determined that the issue is not in my controller, unless there is a direct conflict with the directives. Without implementing directives , and using controllers (the way i had it before attempting this directive method), everything worked fine.

Comment: You said the same thing about it not being the controller in your question.  My problem, however, is I don't see where there is even a controller defined at all here, to tell when in the load order any REST call could be made.  Are you sure the controller is still even being used?